# Use path as inputile instead of file name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-handling, filehandle

I am trying to use the path as input instead of a file name.

I tried

```
from pathlib import path
file_to open = Path (source/input*/in.txt)
with open ('file_to_open', 'r') as f_i:
   for line in f_i:
```

I could not be able to open the path. Please suggest me efficient methods to open the file using a path instead of file name.

Comment: Are you asking to have the user to input in a file path of their choice?

Comment: @AlexDouglas I want to use the path instead of using "in.txt" as input. Not required to be users choice.

Comment: so you just want to find all files in the `input*` path? Is `in.txt` your desired text? I am unclear with what you are requesting.

Comment: @Alex Douglas I want to search all the files which start with the input and find in.txt file

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
...
file_to_open = Path("source/input*/{}.txt".format(input))
...
```

Based on input `input`.

Comment: It is saying input is not defined

Comment: Place `input = input('File name')` before the `file_to_open` line

Comment: Not sure where it is going wrong. It is still giving me error